# Beautiful Soup parsing inline <div> and <p> into dictionary

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working on parsing a pretty nasty site. Basically, there is inline divs (which are 'headers), and paragraph tags beneath (not IN the divs), that are theoretically 'children'... I would like to convert this to a dictionary. I can't quite figure out the best way to do it. Here is roughly what the site looks like:

```
<div><span>This should be dict key1</span></div>
<p>This should be the value of key1</p>
<div><span>This should be dict key2</span></div>
<p>This should be the value of key2</p>
```

So, theoretically (and incorrectly), the python code would go something like this...

```
import bs4 as bs   

dict = {"Key" : "Value"}


soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
for item in soup:
    if item.tag == "div":
        dict['key'] = item.text
        if item.tag == "p":
            dict['value'] = item.text
```

But then somehow, once the next `<div>` is found, it needs to break, and start a new key value. I'm having such a hard time wrapping my head around this... Help!

**UPDATE**
The suggested solution worked beautifully.

Comment: In your example, as far as the HTML is concerned, the `<p>` elements are not children of the `<div>`s. It will be in the same `soup` object where you're currently scanning for `div`s.

Comment: right. so I guess I'm not sure how to differentiate how it handles it... If you find a `div`, make key.. for each `p` after, make it value, BUT if you find another `div`, make that a new key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can firstly find out all the `div`s, then loop through the div list, for each div find out its next sibling tag `p`'s text, add more attribute constraints to the `find_all` function to make sure it gets to where you want it to be:

```
{div.get_text(): div.findNextSibling('p').get_text() for div in soup.find_all("div")}

#{'This should be dict key1': 'This should be the value of key1',
# 'This should be dict key2': 'This should be the value of key2'}
```

---

*Update*: if there are multiple `p` tags following `div`, then simply loop through all divs and find out all `p`s until the next `div` and add them as values to the previous key, here used a `defaultdict` to simplify the logic a little bit:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)

for div in soup.find_all("div"):

    ns = div.nextSibling
    while ns is not None and ns.name != "div":
        if ns.name == "p":
            result[div.text].append(ns.text)
        ns = ns.nextSibling

result
# defaultdict(list,
#             {'This should be dict key1': ['This should be the value of key1',
#              'This should also be the value of key1'],
#              'This should be dict key2': ['This should be the value of key2']})
```

---

*Html used*:

```
<div><span>This should be dict key1</span></div>
<p>This should be the value of key1</p>
<p>This should also be the value of key1</p>
<div><span>This should be dict key2</span></div>
<p>This should be the value of key2</p>
```

Comment: But the `<p>`s are not ACTUALLY siblings... Does this still apply?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. so the example given in OP is not the actual case?

Comment: It is, but look closely, the `div`s are closed. So the subsequent paragraph's aren't IN the divs

Comment: Isn't that what sibling stands for? which means they are not parent and children, i.e. one wraps another, but one follows another?

Comment: @Psidom is right. A sibling in this structure means that they share the same parent. In your example `div` and `p` share the same parent. If `p` was in  a `div`, `p` would be a child of that `div`.

Comment: @Psidom is correct! This does indeed work perfectly. Thank you!!

Comment: I do have one more question... What id there are two `<p>` tags in a row? In this case, it will only add the first one.

Comment: So you want to add both of them as a value of list in this case?

Comment: Yes. Or, maybe add them into a list, then that list could be the value - Either would work.

Comment: @Psidom I'm getting  `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'name'` from the while loop. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `nextSibling` instead of `nextSiblings`? the latter returns a list.

Comment: Can you please ask a new question with some sample data and error messages you get instead of editing the original one? Editing the question makes the original answer invalid.

Comment: Fair enough. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728401/beautiful-soup-paring-div-and-p-tags-into-dictionary