# Beautiful Soup parsing multiple <div> and successive <p> tags into dictionary

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have multiple inline divs (which are 'headers), and paragraph tags beneath (not IN the divs), that are theoretically 'children'... I would like to convert this to a dictionary. I can't quite figure out the best way to do it. Here is roughly what the site looks like:

```
<div><span>This should be dict key1</span></div>
<p>This should be the value of key1</p>
<p>This should be the value of key1</p>
<div><span>This should be dict key2</span></div>
<p>This should be the value of key2</p>
```

The Python code I have working looks like this:

```
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

full_discussion = soup.find(attrs={'class' : 'field field-type-text field-field-discussion'})

ava_discussion = full_discussion.find(attrs = {'class': 'field-item odd'})

for div in ava_discussion.find_all("div"):
    discussion = []

    if div.findNextSibling('p'):
        discussion.append(div.findNextSibling('p').get_text())

    location = div.get_text()

    ava_dict.update({location: {"discussion": discussion}}
```

However, the problem is that this code only adds the FIRST `<p>` tag, then it moves onto the next div. Ultimately, I think I'd like to add each `<p>` into a list into `discussion`. Help!

**UPDATE:**

Adding a `while` loop yields me duplicates of the first

tags for how many exist. Here is the code:

```
for div in ava_discussion.find_all("div"):
    ns = div.nextSibling

    discussion = []

    while ns is not None and ns.name != "div":
        if ns.name == "p":
            discussion.append(div.findNextSibling('p').get_text())
        ns = ns.nextSibling

    location = div.get_text()

    ava_dict.update({location : {"discussion": discussion}})

print(json.dumps(ava_dict, indent=2))
```

Comment: So what's the problem with the `while` loop I suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726507/beautiful-soup-parsing-inline-div-and-p-into-dictionary/42726618#42726618)? Seems to work for me.

Comment: @Psidom see above.

Comment: Ah. problem solved.

Comment: Change line `discussion.append(div.findNextSibling('p').get_text())` to `discussion.append(ns.text)` since you are looping through node in the line `ns = ns.nextSibling` already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't adding the correct text. This code works:

```
for div in ava_discussion.find_all("div"):
    ns = div.nextSibling

    discussion = []

    while ns is not None and ns.name != "div":
        if ns.name == "p":
            discussion.append(ns.get_text())
        ns = ns.nextSibling

    location = div.get_text()

    ava_dict.update({location : {"discussion": discussion}})

print(json.dumps(ava_dict, indent=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
    paragraphs = div.findNextSiblings('p') 
    for sibling in div.findNextSiblings():
        if sibling in paragraphs:
            discussion.append(sibling.get_text())
        else:
            break
```

now, who can show me how to make this more elegant :)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I've revised my answer!